# Returning Django comments for a Tastypie resource

Tags: django, tastypie, django-comments

My Django site has a Photo model which represents photos in the system and I'm using `Django.contrib.comments` to allow users to comment on these.  This is all working fine but I'd like to extend my Tastypie API to allow accessing of comments for my `PhotoResource` using a URL like `/api/v1/photo/1/comments` where 1 is the id of the photo.  I'm able to get the URL to work fine but no matter what sort of filtering I'm doing I always seem to return the complete set of comments rather than just the set for the supplied photo.  I've included a cut down selection of my current code API below:

```
class CommentResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user')
    class Meta:
       queryset = Comment.objects.all()
            filtering = {
                'user': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
            }

class PhotoResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user')  
    class Meta:
        queryset = Photo.objects.all()
        filtering = {
            'id': 'exact',
            'user': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS
        }

    def prepend_urls(self):
        return [url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<pk>\w[\w/-]*)/comments%s$" % (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()), self.wrap_view('get_comments'), name="api_get_comments"),
        ]

    def get_comments(self, request, **kwargs):
        try:
            obj = self.cached_obj_get(request=request, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return HttpGone()
        except MultipleObjectsReturned:
            return HttpMultipleChoices("More than one resource is found at this URI.")
        comment_resource = CommentResource()
        return comment_resource.get_list(request, object_pk=obj.id, content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Photo))
```

As far as I can tell it's the filter in the last line that isn't working.  I think this is slightly complicated due to contrib.comments using ContentTypes to link to the object being commented on which I guess it's possible Tastypie can't cope with.  I've tried a bunch of variations on this but it still doesn't work.  I felt pretty certain something like this would work:

```
ctype = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj)
comment_resource = CommentResource()
return comment_resource.get_list(request, object_pk=obj.pk, content_type_id=ctype.id)
```

but again all comments were returned.

Does anyone have any ideas how to do this (or if it's even possible)?

Comment: Did you solved it? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually instead of hacking it into the PhotoResource I would do a filtering in the CommentResource instead. You have to enable filtering for that model and the url would look like this:

> /api/v1/comment/?object__pk=1&content_type_id=2

Comment: Yup, I considered doing something like that but for me it doesn't really make for a good URL.  I'm never interested in the comments themselves, only comments related to a photo which is why I'd prefer the URL to be in the `/photo/1/comments` format.  I did make some progress on this before getting sidetracked so hopefully I'll be able to share my results soon.

Comment: Hey @Roarster, I'm facing the same issue as well, we're you able to solve it?!

Comment: Unfortunately not.  I ended up abandoning Tastypie and using [Django REST Framework](http://django-rest-framework.org/) instead.  Tastypie was very easy to get going but I really struggled when I needed something outside of the ordinary.  DRF has made this a lot easier although it did take a bit more work to get going.  It also seems to be a bit more active on the development side which is good.